# Speed of water at bottom of an inclined plane

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, navier-stokes

I have a question. We are given an inclined plane with height $h$ and hypotenuse length $d$.

And water is falling down through a hose on the slope. The hose has a inner diameter $l$ and thickness $b$.

Then what value of speed of the water at the bottom of the inclined plane?

I think that this problem perhaps involves Navier-stokes equation and I can't deduce associated formula. Is there an associated data? Where?

Can anyone helps?

Comment: It is not clear how hose placed regarding to plane? Is hose over plane or in plane?

Comment: Uhm, over plane~

Comment: Is viscosity considered in this situtation

Comment: Yes. If viscosity is also considered, it will be good.